# Odd use of parentheses in SQL FROM clause

Tags: sql, mysql

I'm looking at 3rd party code and see parentheses used in a way I've never seen before. I need to understand it so I don't break something.

```
    from 
    (
        (
            (
                (
                    part join product on(part.id = product.partId)
                )
                join soitem on(product.id = soitem.productId)
            )
            join so on(so.id = soitem.soId)
        )
        left join uomconversion on(uomconversion.toUomId = part.uomId and
                                   uomconversion.fromUomId = soitem.uomId)
    )
```

It looks like `part` is joined with `product`, producing a table, which is then joined with `moitem`, producing a second table, and so forth. Perhaps this is forcing evaluation to be in a specified order?

I would have done it in the more usual way,

```
        from part 
        join product on(part.id = product.partId)
        join soitem on(product.id = soitem.productId)
        join so on(so.id = soitem.soId)
        left join uomconversion on(uomconversion.toUomId = part.uomId and
                                       uomconversion.fromUomId = soitem.uomId)
```

Is there any meaningful difference between these two approaches?

Comment: `Is there any meaningful difference between these two approaches?` Why don't you profile the generated SQL and find out?

Comment: The first one is the "table syntax" defined in the SQL Standard. Some databases implement it, but I find it not that useful IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

**No, there is absolutely no difference.**

Parenthesis do not make any difference to the interpretation of a `JOIN`, despite them changing the meaning of scalar operators.

What *does* make a difference is the order of the `ON` clauses, and therefore some people add `()` around such joins to make the meaning clearer. (The same thing could be said for correct spacing.)

For example, your query could have been

```
from part
left join
    product
    join soitem on product.id = soitem.productId
    left join so on so.id = soitem.soId
    join uomconversion on uomconversion.toUomId = part.uomId and
                          uomconversion.fromUomId = soitem.uomId
on part.id = product.partId
```

Which is the same as adding the `()` and maing it clear that the `part` is joined with the *result* of all the other joins

```
from part
left join
(
    product
    join soitem on product.id = soitem.productId
    left join so on so.id = soitem.soId
    join uomconversion on uomconversion.toUomId = part.uomId and
                          uomconversion.fromUomId = soitem.uomId
)
on part.id = product.partId
```

The *only* thing that makes a difference here is that the `ON` clauses are nested:
`FROM a JOIN b JOIN c ON ... ON ...`